# AngularJS controller middleware

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular endpoint like so:

```
$stateProvider.state("auth.signin", {
    url: "/signin",
    views: {
        "auth-view@auth": {
            templateUrl: "views/auth/signin.html",
            controller: "SigninController"
        }
    }
});
```

I want a before filter (or a middleware) for my `SigninController` so if the user is already logged in, I want to redirect him to my `HomeController`.

In pseudo code, I'm looking for something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("auth.signin", {
    url: "/signin",
    views: {
        "auth-view@auth": {
            templateUrl: "views/auth/signin.html",
            controller: "SigninController"
        }
    },
    before: () => {
        if (User.loggedIn() === true) {
            return $state.go("app.home");
        }
    }
});
```

I used similar features on alot of frameworks so I'm pretty certain Angular has something like this too. What's the Angular way of doing it?

Thank you.

Ps: I'm not using Angular 2 yet.

Comment: what you are describing is a `resolve`. See router docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ui router triggers a `$stateChangeStart` event, which you can capture:

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) { 
        if (toState.name === "auth.signin" && userIsLoggedInLogicHere) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent routing to the state
            $state.transitionTo("app.home");
        }
        // else do nothing, it will just transition to the given state
    })
}]);
```

See [this documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) for reference